# Enable/Disable checkbox on click of another checkbox in Repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

On check of one checkbox I want to enable another checkbox in Repeater. How I can do that?
My html code is

```
                <asp:Repeater ID="rptUlAll" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <li id="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "PropertyId")%>">
                            <div>
                                <span>
                                    <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Name")%></span>
                                <asp:CheckBox Visible="false" ID="checkBoxInDropDown" runat="server" Checked="false" ToolTip="<%$ Resources:Resource, RequiredErrorMessage %>" />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxUseInWebService" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server" />
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="checkBoxAllowAccessWebService" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" Enabled="False" />
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Here checkBoxAllowAccessWebService is enable=false, on check of checkBoxUseInWebService I want to make it enable true.

As it is in Repeater, In jquery I was not able to get its id to enable or disable it.
Can any one help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

it is "disabled" :

```
<input type="text" name="" id="" disabled />
```